# Como sacar el costo del envio de una devolucion con API de MercadoLibre?

Tags: api, mercadopago, mercadolibre

Hice un pequeño programa para poder sacar reportes de mis ventas.
Prácticamente ya acomplete todo el programa, sacando con las APIs de MercadoLibre toda la información de las ventas, cancelaciones, comisiones, envíos, reclamos, etc.

Lo único que no he logrado sacar el costo del envío de la devolución, en caso que aplique.
He utilizado las siguientes APIs pero en ninguna encontré un parámetro que indique el costo de la devolución:

https://api.mercadolibre.com/orders/$orderId

https://api.mercadolibre.com/shipments/$shipmentId/costs

https://api.mercadolibre.com/v1/claims/search?id=$mediationId

https://api.mercadolibre.com/v1/reasons/$reasonId/children

https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/$paymentId

Pensé que alomejor pudiera encontrar ese costo si tengo el shipmentId de la devolución, pero tampoco encontré en ningún lugar este parámetro.

Ojala alguien me pudiera ayudar porque llevo una semana sin encontrar la solución.

Comment: Revisaste en la documentación de la Api de mercado libre?

Comment: Deberías poner el código que ha intentado usar

Comment: Claro, ya busque en toda la documentacion de MercadoLibre y no logre encontrar donde esta este parametro.

Mi codigo esta bien, y he logrado sacar todos los parametros que se encuentran disponibles, pero no encuentro donde puedo encontrar el parametro del costo del envio de la devolucion

Comment: Disculpa la pregunta, que URL usaste para obtener el detalle de una venta, tengo un hook que recibe esta información `"payment_id" : "/collections/3043111111"` cuando se hace una compra en mercado libre. Según en la documentación con este dato lo puedes obtener, pero siempre obtengo Payment not found
`{ "message": "Payment not found", "error": "not_found", "status": 404, "cause": { "code": 2000, "description": "Payment not found", "data": null }
}` Saludos cordiales